# Android app: Button counting variable up or down

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to display a variable, which the user should be able to count up and down with 2 buttons. Here is my code. Problem is it does not seem to work. If you hit "minues" then "1" appears, if you hit "plus" nothing happens. Thanks a lot!

I know switch might not be the most elegant solution but I still would like to try it

```
public class StoryCreator extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_creator);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);   
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);   
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

    public void onClick(View v) {

        int Zahl = 1;    

        TextView objekt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        objekt.setText("0");

       // Perform action on click
          switch(v.getId())
          {

             case 1: 
                                    Zahl = Zahl-1;
                                    break;
             case 2:
                                    Zahl = Zahl+1;
                                    break;
             default:           
                                    break;
         }


            switch(Zahl) {
            case -1: 
                objekt.setText("-1");
                break;
            case 0: 
                objekt.setText("0");
                break;
            case 1:
                objekt.setText("1");
                break;              
            case 2:
                objekt.setText("2");
                break;      
            case 3:
                objekt.setText("3");
                break;      

            }
```

Comment: The kind advice is to go back to some tutorials.  Java basics first, then Android Hello World.  As Pavel says, there are many problems in your code.  In fact, it's rare to see such a short piece of code with so many errors.  Sorry to be blunt, but the truth is the best thing.

Answer (score 2):

Change your switch case as :

```
   // Perform action on click
      switch(v.getId())
      {

         case R.id.minus: 
             Zahl = Zahl-1;
              break;
         case R.id.plus:
             Zahl = Zahl+1;
             break;
         default:           
             break;
     }
```

use Button id instead of 1,2 to perform action according to Button click

Comment: well, there are much more problems in his code. Your solution will fix only buttons id problem :) With the logic given, it will not be counting down anyways.

Comment: @PavelDudka : with my solution both button get worked and OP will improve logic according to Application behavior. im right or i will edit my answer with full code?

Comment: don't think there is a need to edit the answer since you pointed out the most important issue in his code. Other mistakes are related to business logic, so only OP knows what exactly his app should do :)

Answer (score 0):

also You set

```
 int Zahl = 1;
```

on every button click, and value of Zahl could be only 0 or 1

```
public class StoryCreator extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


int mValue = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_creator);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);   
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);   
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

    public void onClick(View v) {


        TextView objekt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

       // Perform action on click
          switch(v.getId())
          {

             case R.id.plus: 
                                    mValue++;
                                    break;
             case R.id.minus:
                                    mValue--;
                                    break;
             default:           
                                    break;
         }

          objekt.setText(mValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is bunch of problems in your code:

- you use the wrong way to reference buttons
- you do not store previous value properly
- you do not increment previous value properly
- etc. :)

Try this code out:

```
public class StoryCreator extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_creator);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);   
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);   
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("0"); //initial value

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());    

       // Perform action on click
          switch(v.getId())
          {

             case R.id.plus: 
                                    Zahl++;
                                    break;
             case R.id.minus:
                                    Zahl--;
                                    break;
             default:           
                                    break;
         }

         textView.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for this! As suggested I guess I will go back to some beginner tutorials... :-) This code works though and I will keep working.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way to do this is to remove the "implements View.OnClickListener" and just create click listeners for each button.

Also, the above solutions still don't actually increment a single variable.  If you want your increment to be persistent across instances, you'll need to turn it into a static.

The following will get you what you need, and do so cleanly without polluting your activity with the View.OnClickListener.

```
public class StoryCreator extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    private static int zahl = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_creator);

        Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);   
        minus.setOnClickListener(minusClickListener);

        Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);   
        plus.setOnClickListener(plusClickListener);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("0"); //initial value

    }

    private View.OnClickListener minusClickListener= new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              zahl--;
        }
    } 

    private View.OnClickListener plusClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             zahl++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its a bit messy but this should do exatly what you want.

```
public class CountUpAction extends AbstractAction {
      /** Constructor */
      public CountUpAction(String name, String shortDesc, Integer mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDesc);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                    switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1:

            //original count
            count += 1;
            tfCount.setText(count + "");

                    }
                }
              });
      }
   }

   public class CountDownAction extends AbstractAction {
      /** Constructor */
      public CountDownAction(String name, String shortDesc, Integer mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDesc);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2:

          //original count
          count -= 1;
          tfCount.setText(count + "");

                }
            }
          });
      }
 Action countUpAction = new CountUpAction("Count Up",
            "", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER));
      Action countDownAction = new CountDownAction("Count Down",
            "", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_D));


  tfCount = new JTextField("0", 8);
      tfCount.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
      tfCount.setEditable(false);
      tfCount.setSize(100, 20);
      canvas.add(tfCount, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

  //Invisible
      JButton btnCountUp = new JButton();
      btnCountUp.setFocusable(false);
      btnCountUp.setHideActionText(true);
      btnCountUp.setContentAreaFilled(false);
      btnCountUp.setBorderPainted(false);
      canvas.add(btnCountUp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      //Invisible
      JButton btnCountDown = new JButton();
      btnCountDown.setFocusable(false);
      btnCountDown.setHideActionText(true);
      btnCountDown.setContentAreaFilled(false);
      btnCountDown.setBorderPainted(false);

      canvas.add(btnCountDown);
      // Set actions for buttons
      btnCountUp.setAction(countUpAction);
      btnCountDown.setAction(countDownAction);
```